# python for android # Command failed: /usr/bin/python -m pythonforandroid.toolchain

Tags: python, kivy, buildozer

I am doing an app for android and I am using python language but there is some errors appearing.

it shows many errors but I managed to reduce it to what I am currently at now.

```
    File "/home/kivy/Desktop/myproject/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-new-toolchain/pythonforandroid/recipes/python2/__init__.py", line 53, in build_arch
    join(self.ctx.get_python_install_dir(), 'bin', 'python.host'))
  File "pythonforandroid/logger.py", line 175, in shprint
    for line in output:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sh.py", line 720, in next
    self.wait()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sh.py", line 651, in wait
    self.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sh.py", line 672, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_1: 

  RAN: /bin/cp /home/kivy/Desktop/myproject/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/other_builds/hostpython2/desktop/hostpython2/hostpython /home/kivy/Desktop/myproject/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/python-installs/myapp/bin/python.host

  STDOUT:
/bin/cp: cannot create regular file '/home/kivy/Desktop/myproject/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/python-installs/myapp/bin/python.host': No such file or directory


  STDERR:
```

> Command failed: /usr/bin/python -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create
>   --dist_name=myapp --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=kivy,hostpython2 --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir="/home/kivy/Desktop/myproject/.buildozer/android/platform/build"
>         Buildozer failed to execute the last command The error might be hidden in the log above this error Please read the full log, and
>   search for it before raising an issue with buildozer itself. In case
>   of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2

here are the things that is written in the terminal